# How to plot a chart in the frontend using data from the backend with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, frontend, backend

My current situation is this:

I have a SQL database that I get my data from on the server side, and I want to show that data in a chart for the user, using *Plotly*. But I'm not sure how to approach this: should I pass the data to the frontend and make a chart there, or make the chart on the server side and try to change the content of the *HTML*?

Also, in the front end, I would like to use a external script, meaning I can't include *plotly* as a module, but maybe there is a way to do it? 
And if I try to do it on the server side, how should I approach this passing the chart to the front end?

I'm fairly new to web development thing, trying to grasp the right concept of how data should be passed arround.

Comment: `should I pass the data to the frontend and make a chart there` - yes, this is quite common solution. `I would like to use a external script, meaning I can't include plotly as a module` - no but there are a lot of js libraries to draw charts.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an api, this api will serve x and y coordinates in array format.
Please refer following link https://plot.ly/javascript/getting-started/#hello-world-example (in this web-page click on js tab and see the "x" and "y" coordinates.)

Next make ajax call to above api and subscribe the response.